# Ubuntu 22.04 touchpad and keyboard freeze randomly

Tags: kernel, touchpad, 22.04, hardware, hp-touchpad

I'm using laptop (HP 15-da3034ur) with ubuntu22.04 on it. But I have some issues with it. After some random time (from 5 to even 60 minutes) from starting of the OS, my keyboard and touchpad just suddenly stop working at the same time. However mouse, connected to the USB port still works. If I suspend machine (basically, close and reopen my laptop), both of devices start working again.

This problem also occurred during the first installation and in Boot Repair program. I've updated ubuntu, Xserver drivers, changed kernel options like in other guides (adding i8042 options to grub config), but problem didn't go away. One thing I've noticed is when I shutdown my system **only** after this freeze, last line in shutdown log is **"psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1"**.

By looking through other questions on this topic, I found out that apparently my laptop uses keyboard&mouse as a single USB device, and kernel (my version is 5.15.0-47-generic) has bad compatibility with that. But I haven't found out how to fix it.

If anyone faced and dealt with this problem, please answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Report a bug to Launchpad.

Comment: let me guess, AMD Ryzen.. I have three Hp X360's. An Asus Ryzen is in the mail for me. I eagerly await to see how that goes. I have the latest BIOS for my main X360 here.

you could play around with suspending this way... though I suppose if the keyboard is not working you cannot make it happen.

echo '1-1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind; sleep 1 ; sudo pm-suspend  ;sleep 1 ; echo '1-1' | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind

Comment: nah, Intel i5 & Intel UHD Graphics, still haven't found a solution. Apparently, it's connected to psmouse somehow, because restarting psmouse drivers helps. BTW, any results in your issue?

Answer (score 1):

(not sure)
Looks like your problem is related to System Suspend (or Sleep) when you close the lid.
Try to configure your system not to fall asleep on lid close.

I'm on Lenovo Thinkpad P1 Gen2.
And I experience like problem with my touchpad when I suspend laptop and wake it up. Restarting driver with `rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse` usually helps.

AFAIK, there is no fixes for this problematic `psmouse` behavior on MANY systems to date, althrough problems are noted widely.

UP: Look also here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchpad_Synaptics
Hopefully, it'll give you more hints. And, try to search this wiki for `psmouse` - it could relate as well.

Comment: `rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse` helps, but I'm only able to run it by plugging in external usb mouse (which works fine) and typing with screen keyboard. After searching some forums I saw that similar problem is solved by adding `psmouse.intertouch=0` to grub options, but this doesn't work for me. I have [another topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451970/touchpad-and-keyboard-of-my-laptop-randomly-freezing), where I try to solve it by different approach, if you have any ideas please share

Comment: what's more interesting, if I type something on my keyboard during the bug (nothing happens, obviously) and then restart psmouse, I have my typed text instantly printed in terminal. Not sure if this is helpful, just in case